# How to create Custom Action in C#.net project with InstallShield?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, installshield-2015

I have c#.net project. I save user data in AppData folder. I want to notify user  about location of AppData when they uninstall the application. I am using InstallShield-2015 for setup purpose.

I have following System.

VisualStudio-2013

InstallShield-2015

I have read about to create Custom Action to achieve above requirement. But I don't have idea how/where to create Custom Action.

Can anybody suggest me link or way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer.

1- Need to create a .vbs or .js script. (Provide path in msgbox in script)

2- Create Custom Action from Custom Action and Sequence.

3- Set .vbs script after "After InstallValidate" and set condition "REMOVE ="ALL""